# Edit PHP file using API in PHP

Tags: php

I am new in PHP and want to develop one single file in PHP API which edit all my js file,css file and html file at single window without login into webhost.Simple I just surf that one link and get edit those file and automatically save on those which I done changes.

Every js should be in different section,similarly for css in one single page.It should also compatible with mobile so I can use in all screen resolution.

Comment: There's not a question anywhere in that?

Comment: Question is that how should I move in order to develop?

Comment: So you want to make a text editor which support php,js,css? is it?

Comment: @Sumant:yes correct!!!!!

Comment: @John: Yes, in the sense that you should first try, and if you fail ask for help (describing what you've tried).

Comment: @AlixAxel ok I will try and let you know :)

Comment: @John: Such kind of questions are normally considered off-topic. Please consider a more fitting forum or peer-group you can ask that question to, you probably want to attend a PHP-User-Group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be careful!!! if u r making such text editor which supports PHP,JS,CSS & HTML using PHP that it will be as Online tool, it may create some security issue, if someone get access to this editor it can be dangerous. But if you don't allow anyone to edit any php file present in your server or even dont allow to use any php function.

And if you concern only about syntax of PHP,JS,CSS just to check & let user know about this than you need to write a lexical parser which will analyze the code with the syntax database for that language.

Due to this Security issue only there are client-side applications like Eclipse,Netbeans,Notepad++ like editors. So just think of this concern also. it should not harm u.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you need to build PHP app that browse your site directory and open plain-text-based files in simple plain text editor.

Research following:
**PHP form processing** (dealing with $_POST data, pay attention to stripslashes() and htmlspecialchars() functions as PHP-processed plain text data can give you a headache)
**PHP filesystem functions**(fopen, fread, fwrite, file_get_contents, scandir, is_dir functions)